# Check SHA-256 Laravel

Tags: laravel, sha256

I have a system that requires a homeowner to submit a form about their guest's details. When they submit a form, each will be assigned a unique 6-digit code. This code will be hashed with SHA-256. In the admin's view, there is a list of all submitted forms. I want to do a search function where when I enter the code, the system will look through the hashed code and check if it exists or not.

This is my GuestController:

```
public function index()
    {
        //returns admin's view
        $guest = Guest::all();
        return view('pages.guest.index', compact('guest'));
    }
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $guest = new Guest;
        $guest->code = random_int(100000, 999999);
        $guest->hash = hash('sha256', $guest['code']);  
        $guest->owner_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $guest->owner = Auth::user()->name;
        $guest->unit = Auth::user()->unit;
        $guest->guestname = $request->input('guestname');
        $guest->guestphone = $request->input('guestphone');
        $guest->guestic = $request->input('guestic');
        $guest->guestcar = $request->input('guestcar');
        $guest->numberofguests = $request->input('numberofguests');
        $guest->datevisit = $request->input('datevisit');
        $guest->timevisit = $request->input('timevisit');
        $guest->save();
        
        return redirect('show-pass')->with('status', 'Guest Added Successfully');
    }
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //Get the search value from the request
        $search = $request->input('search');

        //Search in the code from the list
        $guest = Guest::query()
                ->where('code', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->get();
               
        //Return the search view with the results compacted
        return view('pages.guest.search', compact('guest'));

    }
```

This is my search result blade:

```
<div class="card-body">
                @if($guest->isNotEmpty())
                        @foreach ($guest as $item)
                            <div class="post-list">          
                                <p>Owner : {{ $item->owner }}</p>
                                <p>Unit : {{ $item->unit }}</p>                 
                                <p>Guest Name : {{ $item->guestname }}</p>
                                <p>Guest Phone Number : {{ $item->guestphone }}</p>
                                <p>Guest IC Number : {{ $item->guestic }}</p>
                                <p>Guest Car Number : {{ $item->guestcar }}</p>
                                <p>Date : {{ $item->datevisit }}</p>
                                <p>Time : {{ $item->timevisit }}</p>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @else 
                        <div>
                        <h4>No guests with the code was found</h4>
                        </div>
                @endif
             </div>
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If yes, how can I edit my search method to be able to do so? May I get some help?

Comment: What is the problem you're having? You seem to be saving the unhashed value into the  object and using that for searching?

Comment: @miken32 I'm just trying the search function to see if it works. So far, it does. When I enter the code as the input for searching, it displays the output that I want (guest's details). Now, what I want to do is to check if the code I enter is in the ```$guest->hash``` (hashed code) list. Can you understand me?

Comment: So you have to pull every single record from the database and do a hash check against it. It's not very efficient. Why do these numbers need to be hashed?

Comment: @miken32 my project is entitled hashed qr code authentication gating system, where it generates qr code that contain the unique code. However, in the back end, I want to hash the code so that nobody can create their own unique code. So, I want to check if the hashed code exists or not. I want to do it kinda like password check. Do you know?